# Can't run Fuze Basic remotely with tighVNC

Tags: vnc

I started successfully `vncserver :1 -geometry 1024x728 -depth 24` on my raspberry pi. Then connected successfully with tight VNC, ran many apps remotly, but when double click on Fuze Basic, it looks like there is no response. Although I can ran it directly using mouse and keyboard connected to raspberry pi.

Is it something related to permission?
The properties of all other application shows the  Owneras  "pi", group as "pi", but Fuze Basic shows Owner "root", group "root".

Comment: You need to consider that some applications that run on the Pi exclusively output through the HDMI or the RCA video port.

Answer (score 1):

```
ssh pi@ip -X
```

in a terminal and then running fuze remotely should render the fb window locally